# OneToMany relationship only return one element

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I´m suffering a really wierd behavior I have one to many relationship between 2 entities (A,B). Everything it´s ok when I add one element (B). But as soon as I add the second one(B1). The register is created on the database and I can see the two entities pointing the same entity(A). "But" as soon as I retrieve A I can see that in the list only has the first A and with all the attributes as null but the id. My relationships are like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
@XmlElement
@Getter
@Setter
private List<B> Bs = new ArrayList<>();




 @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
@Getter @Setter
private A a;
```

What it´s wrong here?

SOLUTION:Was my fault, one of the enums values on my B1 was not ok and Hibernate was not complaining about it. After try to get the values directly from the database without A I receive the exception.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect mapping on A > B:

```
public class A{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<B> Bs;
}


public class B{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;
}
```

And as suggested in another answer, if your adding Bs to A and persisting A, then set both side of the relationship. You should encapsulate add/remove operations to enforce integrity of the model.

```
public class A{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<B> Bs;

    public List<B> getBs(){
        return Collections.unmodificableList(Bs);
    }

    public void addB(B b){
        b.setA(this);
        Bs.add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had that mapping before as well, I´m tried everything. The entities on database are correct. Both Bs are pointing to A. I think it´s something that Hibernate is messing up

Answer (score 0):

We need your service code to be able to know for sure what the problem is. But, my guess is that you didn't add that `b1` to `A`'s list of `Bs`. If that's the case, your next query for `A` is returning it from the cache, where it doesn't have `b1` in its list.

Bottom line is, if my assumption is correct, you need to handle both sides of bidirectional relationship.

```
B b1 = new B();
b1.setA(a);
// I guess you are skipping this next step
a.getBs().add(b1);
save(a);
```

Comment: I was doing that already, the entity on database it´s correct. Both Bs are pointing to A. I think it´s something that Hibernate is messing up

Comment: It´s fixed, at the end was not an hibernate mapping issue, thanks for the help by the way

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, wrong equals/hashcode methods was the issue (for Hibernate, two of database objects where the same entity - due to problems with methods mentioned above, so it returned only one of them)